# Swift Read HTML elements on webpage

Tags: swift, parsing, html, display

I am trying to read a specific text on a website, and I was wondering how I would proceed doing so. I am trying to get the followers-count on the instagram website, to then retrieve it in my app and display it. How would I proceed with this?

I have searched both Google and GitHub for parser, with no luck - and there is no tutorial on YouTube explaining how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use RegEx, or NSScanner

Answer (score 1):

Usually for something like this, you'll want to use the [official API.](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

Isolating and reading an element in web page is likely not what you want to do. An API gives you access to parts of a service an application might need to interact with, just like this.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. However, I am not in need of any authentication or anything - simply just be able to pull the amount of posts by a user, and its followers. Do you still think that I need this API?

Comment: I think doing this without an API would be more trouble than just using it.